# Why creating a class and calling the class function suspend any visual change

Tags: java, jframe

i have a frame class , and when the user click a button i want to process something that takes some time, so i've wanted to write wait somewhere that the user will know that the process started when he clicked the button . 
but it doesnt change anything visual until the function that create a class and call the classe's function ends , even that i call it after i try to write something , the text changes only after the function returns a result.

```
btnNewButton.setText("wait...");
```

this line doesn't being executed until this function ends -

```
 boolean suc=create_comp();
```

even thought this line is after the other.
how can i show something to the user that he will know that the process is running? 
these are the relevant parts of the code -

```
public static boolean create_comp(){
    return new Main(Company_name.getText(),company_description.getText(),folder,path).Create_comp();
}

public void initialize{
  ....
        btnNewButton = new JButton("Create Company");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 238, 434, 23);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(!Company_name.getText().equals("")&& folder!=null){
                    btnNewButton.setText("wait...");
                    btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);
                    boolean suc=create_comp();
                    btnNewButton.setEnabled(true);
                    if(suc){
                        Company_name.setText("");
                        company_description.setText("");
                        finished.setText("finished ! ");
                    }

....
}
```

thanks ahead.

Comment: A single thread can do only one thing at a time. You're doing an expensive operation in the event dispatch thread, so you're preventing it to do what it should do: paint the UI and react to events. Read the swing concurrency tutorial, and use a SwingWorker.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). Please read and follow the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), use *camelCase* instead of underscores in your identifiers.

Comment: hi , thanks for your fast answer , but i dont want it to do several things at the same time , i want it to wait for the result and do nothing at this time . i just want that when the user clicks the button i will write something to the user **before** i start the expensive operation. i still need to use this SwingWorker? @JBNizet

Comment: The loop is basically 1. wait for event; 2. invoke event listeners; 3. repaint; 4.go to 1. So, if the thread is busy doing step 2, it can't get to step 3 and repaint the UI. And it can't react to other events either. Yes, you must use a SwingWorker.

Comment: ok , thanks a lot. ill read about SwingWorker.